# How to initialize Swift array with nil

Tags: swift

I am trying to have `nil` for zeroth index element and rest will have value of Generic type `T` which is `Comparable`.

So when I initialise it will `nil` it works as expected

```
struct Container<T: Comparable> {
    var container = [T?]()

    init() {
        container.append(nil)
    }
}
```

but when I do it with an integer say 0, I get `ambiguous reference`

```
struct Container<T: Comparable> {
    var container = [T?]()

    init() {
        container.append(0)
    }
} 

Playground execution failed: error: Algorithms.playground:7:9: error: ambiguous reference to member 'append'
        container.append(0)
        ^~~~~~~~~
```

I want to understand why this error is occurring?

Comment: `T` is not necessary `Int` – it could be `String`, and `0` cannot be added to a `[String?]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` can by *any* comparable type (`String`,  a custom type, ...),
and initializing it from `0` is not generally
possible.

You could require that  `T` can be created from an integer literal,
this covers all integer and floating point types:

```
struct Container<T: Comparable> where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    var container = [T?]()

    init() {
        container.append(0)
    }
}
```

Or provide a separate `append()` method:

```
struct Container<T: Comparable> {
    var container = [T?]()

    init() {
        container.append(nil)
    }

    mutating func append(_ newElement: T) {
        container.append(newElement)
    }
} 

var c = Container<Int>()
c.append(0)
```

Comment: doesn't this defeat the purpose of having container as a generic type?

Comment: @RajeevBhatia: It is still generic, just for a restricted set of types. If you don't restrict it then `append(0)` makes no sense.

Comment: @MartinR I though Array should have `append` method and if I am providing `T` type literal then it should behave as it supposed to.

Comment: @Rahul: Then how should `let c = Container<String>()` work? What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `T: Comparable` does not necessarily mean Int, it means ANY value that conforms to `Comparable`, which includes `String`, `Float`, `Bool`, and the thousands of custom structs other programmers have written for their own projects.

Since 0 is not a valid value for all of these Structs, you essentially have one of two issues:

1) Do I actually just want the Container to always use `Int` - in which case:

```
struct Container
{
    var container: [Int?]

    init()
    {
        container = [nil]
    }
}

var a = Container()
a.container.append (0)
```

2) Why am I using 0, when I mean `nil`

```
struct Container<T: Comparable>
{
    var container: [T?]

    init()
    {
        container = [nil]
    }
}

var a = Container<Int>()
a.container.append (0)
```